# C Macro Wizardry for multiplying a statement N times

Tags: c, macros, embedded

I have the following macros that take a statement and multiply it

```
#define X2(s)  do { s; s; } while (0)
#define X3(s)  do { s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X4(s)  do { s; s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X5(s)  do { s; s; s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X6(s)  do { s; s; s; s; s; s; } while (0)
etc.
```

so the pre-processor expands

```
X2(i++)
```

to

```
do { i++; i++; } while (0)
```

I would like to have a macro

```
#define CODE_MULTIPLIER(x,s)
```

which expands a statement `s`, `x` times. so

```
CODE_MULTIPLIER(3,j--)
```

would be expanded to

```
do { j--; j--; j--; } while (0)
```

The ugly idea i came up with is:

```
#define CODE_MULTIPLIER(x,s) do {       \
       if ((x) == 1) { s; }             \
  else if ((x) == 2) { s; s; }          \
  else if ((x) == 3) { s; s; s; }       \
  else if ((x) == 4) { s; s; s; s; }    \
  else if ((x) == 5) { s; s; s; s; s; } \
  etc.                                  \
  else assert(0);                       \
  } while (0)
```

hoping the compiler will optimize out the `if`s

Why would you ever want macros like this?
One reason (but not the only one) is the need for *exact* delays in embedded programming. using while/for loops slightly change the timing. Compiler optimization of loops may not preserve delicate timing requirements.

Here is a typical usage example:

```
#define CLOCK_FREQ_Hz      (16000000L)
#define US_TO_NOPS(us)     ((us) * CLOCK_FREQ_Hz / 1000000L)

#define OFF_ON_DELAY_US    (4) // units: microseconds
#define ON_OFF_DELAY_US    (2) // units: microseconds

#define OFF_ON_DELAY_NOPS US_TO_NOPS(OFF_ON_DELAY_US) // units: instructions
#define ON_OFF_DELAY_NOPS US_TO_NOPS(ON_OFF_DELAY_US) // units: instructions

PIN = OFF;
CODE_MULTIPLIER(OFF_ON_DELAY_NOPS,asm("nop")); // 4us delay
PIN = ON;
CODE_MULTIPLIER(ON_OFF_DELAY_NOPS,asm("nop")); // 2us delay
PIN = OFF;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to create this macro. High preference to compiler-independent macro wizardry (Us embedded dudes don't always have the luxury of using GCC)

Thanx

Comment: Couldn't you do some _macro wizardry_ to instead use a `for` loop?  (If you insist upon using macros.)

Comment: @devnull: edited question to explain why loops may be problematic when  timing requirements are stringent.

Comment: Just for reference, if you read or wrote to a `volatile` object within a `for` loop, the compiler would not be allowed to optimize it away and still call itself a C compiler.

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer: you could probably still do with a loop, and force your specific compiler to unroll it?

Comment: You should really use compiler pragmas to disable optimization on function that requires precise timing, and/or do it with assembler. It is not portable, but micro/nano second timings rarely are.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: you are correct. But even unoptimized while loops may take different number of instructions on different architectures

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer You have to disable your optimization in any case because otherways you risk that your `i--; i--,` gets optimized in `i-=2`. But also than you have to check that it is not. You may prefer to use inline assembly to force that instruction.

Comment: Not only is your "ugly idea" ugly, it does not have a constant execution time for any value of x. It evaluates `(x) == <some integer>` x times.  A switch would be more deterministic for a continuous monotonic sequence, but is still not simply a sequence statements `s`, so has overhead which in your NOP delay example would be significant.

Comment: @Clifford: that is why i wrote "hoping the compiler would optimize out the ifs"

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer:  It seems unlikely, and "hope" is not a good basis on which to meet your performance requirements - it will vary between compiler and with different compiler options. At best it might spot the idiom and convert it to a switch, so you may as well use a switch.  A switch with sequential integer cases will be implemented as a jump table, which will at least have a *fixed* overhead independent of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such things are possible if you don't stretch things too much. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/utilities.html#condi) has a whole series of macros to accomplish different sorts of such unrolling. An easy one here would be

```
#define toto(I) f(I)

P99_UNROLL(toto, 3);  // => f(0); f(1); f(2);
```

But beware that for using P99 you'd need a compiler that implements C99 compliant preprocessor.

Comment: I like C99, +1 for the nice advice.

Answer (score 1):

As recursion cannot be generally used in macros, and you may not have "extended unrolling features" the only way to have a "always valid solution" is to do some manual work like following one:

```
#define X1(s)  do { s;} while (0)
#define X2(s)  do { s; s; } while (0)
#define X3(s)  do { s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X4(s)  do { s; s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X5(s)  do { s; s; s; s; s; } while (0)
#define X6(s)  do { s; s; s; s; s; s; } while (0)
#define CODE_MULTIPLIER(s, i) X##i(s)
```

And you just use `CODE_MULTIPLIER(s, i)` in your code. In this way you avoid the if/else if conditional expressions. For example you will use `CODE_MULTIPLIER(i++,3)`.
Another trick can be applied if you aren't going to use X1,X2.... but only CODE_MULTIPLIER(s,i):

```
#define X1(s)  s
#define X2(s)  s; X1(s)
#define X3(s)  s; X2(s)
#define X4(s)  s; X3(s)
#define X5(s)  s; X4(s)
#define X6(s)  s; X5(s)
#define CODE_MULTIPLIER(s, i) do { X##i(s); } while (0)
```

which has a nicer sintax.

Comment: Neat. After some arbitrary value you might reduce the resolution so for example to skip from 25 to 30 repeats without the intervening values: `#define X30(s) X5(s); X25(s)` to get a wider range of values in fewer lines.  By defining just decades, you could build up arbitrary repeats, so for example for 1234 repeats: `X1000(s);X200(s);X30(s);X4(s)`, which is still fairly readable without having to define 1234 separate macros.